# How can I take a screenshot of my app and share it in Android Studio?

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I want to implement a button on my app that can let the user take a screenshot of the app and then share it as image on  social networks, but I don't know how to do that, I've tried with Bitmap but didn't work.

This is what I've done, but is not working:

```
public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
       View screenView = view.getRootView();
       screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
       screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
       return bitmap;
 }
```

Hope you can help me :D

Comment: Do you receive any error? Also there is no need to create bitmap from a bitmap. Just use `Bitmap bitmap = screenView.getDrawingCache();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android